# Highcharts: Why text of dataLabels inside column bar are not getting justified and are overflowing

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts column chart. Here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/fkk4b/5/).

Now my problem is:

- As you can see, the text of the `dataLabel` of the first column is
  overflowing and moving outside of the bar area instead of being
  constrained inside the bar area and getting justified. **To be specific : the `dataLabel` text `This is column 1. This is column 1. This is column 1.` should be constrained inside the first column bar with x-axis category `Smallest Priority` which is of `red` color instead of overflowing and moving out of the red colored column bar**. I have
  referred [plotOptions.series.dataLabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels)  documentation and used
  the options like:

  ```
  series: {
  dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'center',
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      inside: true,
      overflow:"justify"//should work but it is not working
  },
  pointPadding: 0.1,
  groupPadding: 0
  ```

  }

Also when `drilldown`, the `dataLabels` are getting cropped and the overflowing text is getting hidden. For that I tried options like:

```
dataLabels: {
    format: 'This is drilldown of column 1',
    crop:false,
    overflow:"justify"
},
```

but this also doesn't seem working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated ! Thanks !!

Comment: For first case, shouldn't be `overflow: 'none'`? Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fkk4b/6/ About second issue, I'm not sure what is wrong..

Comment: Shouldn't it be `overflow:"justify"` ??

Comment: Why? Read [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow): `The default is justify, which aligns them inside the plot area.`.

Comment: Then why it is overflowing and moving out of the column bar area ?? I have much expectations from you, my dear friend, as you have helped me twice previously !  :)

Comment: Pardon? `justify` = fit dataLabel to plotting area. `none` - display according to options, won't fit dataLabel to plotting area. I'm not sure what is your question :)

Comment: I have edited my question and added a line in bold to clarify what do I mean to say specifically ! Hope this time you get idea of what problem is ! :)

Comment: Then why just don't you set width for labels? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fkk4b/7/

Comment: I tried setting width of `dataLabels`, that is working fine. But my charts needs to be responsive. I such a scenario the fixed width in pixels will be problemetic. What would I do in such a scenario. You can look at my current fiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/fkk4b/8/

Comment: Then on window.resize, you need to update series with new `dataLabels.style.width` property. Highcharts doesn't provide option for dataLabels like 'fit to column' or anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used `dataLabels.style.width` property to constrain the `dataLabels` text inside the column bars. Here is my updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/fkk4b/9/)**

code to set width of dataLabels:

```
dataLabels: {
     style:{
             width:100
     }
}
```